# jQuery Prepend Open Tag Append Closing Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, prepend

Firstly, I am familiar with .`wrapAll()` and that is not what I need. I have some markup that I am not able to change and I need to wrap everything in a `<li>`.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```js
$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul a').wrap('<li></li>');

$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul li:last').after('<li>');

$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul').append('</li>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav role="breadcrumb">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <a href="http://eggaday.armystage.com/">Home</a>
    <a href="http://eggaday.armystage.com/health-care-professionals/">Health Care Professionals</a> Healthy Choices Cholesterol Kits
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The problem is that jQuery closes each of these `<li>` tags. Here is the original markup:

```html
<nav role="breadcrumb">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <a href="http://eggaday.armystage.com/">Home</a>
    <a href="http://eggaday.armystage.com/health-care-professionals/">Health Care Professionals</a> Healthy Choices Cholesterol Kits
  </ul>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I have some loose text at the bottom of this `<ul>` and I am trying to get it wrapped in an `<li>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.contents()` will get all the children, including the text nodes

```
$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul').contents().filter(function() {
   return $.trim($(this).text())!=="";
}).wrap('<li/>');
```

EDIT: Added the filter method to get rid of the whitespace text nodes

Comment: lol yea this is so close! But I do get 2 empty LIs in my UL, which sadly mucks things up a bit :(

Answer (score 0):

jQuery only works with complete elements, you can't append just a closing or opening tag.

If the ul doesn't have any other list items, you could simply use wrapInner

```
$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul').wrapInner("<li />");
```

If it does contain LI's, the easiest way would be to detach them, wrap inner, then append them.

```
var $lis = $('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul > li').detach();
$('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul').wrapInner("<li />").prepend($lis);
```

Comment: Is there any sort of hack to this? Any way at all I can do what I am attempting?

Comment: I appreciate the help but unfortunately this doesn't seem to solve the problem. The first bit of code for wrapInner wraps everything in my UL in a single LI tag, when I need both the As and that final bit of text each wrapped in an LI. When using jQuery to wrap each A in an LI then using your code with $lis... nothing seems to happen at all :(

Comment: It would be easy if it weren't for the plain text in the UL. Did you try my second snippet? it's supposed to take into account having existing LI's in the ul.

Comment: Yea i tried using $('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul a').wrap('<li></li>'); followed by the two lines of code in the second snippet and it didn't do anything :( That last line is still unwrapped.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your <li> first and then append your selector to it:

```
var $li = $('<li>').append('nav[role="breadcrumb"] ul a');
```

Then use $li to replace or append anywhere you like.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but unfortunately I couldn't get this to work :(